# how to get the content of a dt element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the content of the dt element using jquery.

```
var test_name = $('dt').text();
alert(test_name);

<dt> cycle_1 </dt>
```

This is not working. What I'm doing wrong? Meaning the alert message does not display.

Comment: Your code **does work**: http://jsfiddle.net/dVwWN/

Comment: What's the complete code you're using? It works for me.

Comment: I went to far deep in th selector level but all your help was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    var test_name = $('dt').text();
    alert(test_name);
});

</script>

<dt> cycle_1 </dt>
```

You need the code to run after page loaded and all jQuery stuff. So, you use `$document.ready(/* some function containing your code */)` for this. The shortcut for this is `$(/* function */)`, then you pass your code in anonymous function (don't have to name it).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are loading the jQuery library properly? Are you using `$(document).ready(function () { .. });`? Here is a jsFiddle of it working:  [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6WJp/)